# Twitch m3u8 url viewers limit?

Tags: url, stream, live, twitch, m3u8

So my question is i am extracting m3u8 url of twitch live stream using a website and copy that url into my android application where users can view that stream using a video player of my app within my app.

Problem is that after running for a few hours the link breaks and i cant run that link anymore and then i have to extrct another m3u8 url to play the stream again.

Is it because the m3u8 url has a certain viewers limit or a time limit? But the time i have noticed that stream runs for hours sometimes without any problem even 10 hrs straight. So I assume that there is certain user limit on every url that is generated?

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to do something that Twitch doesn't support.

The correct method to embed a Twitch stream *somewhere else* is to use the documented iFrame embeds https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed/

Since your android application is already "using a website" then your website jsut needs - `<iframe src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=mychannel"></iframe>`